# Write zip file from post request to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Python 2.7

I have the following function:

```
def download(args):
    payload = {'foo': args.foo,
               'bar': args.bar, 'baz': args.baz}
    try:
      r = requests.post(URL, data=payload, verify='chain.crt')
    except requests.ConnectionError:
      raise
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
      if r.content is not None:
        with closing(r), zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(r.content)) as zip:
          zip.printdir()
      # Save file as file name provided by argparse: args.filename
      # here
      else:
        return False
```

This script does a post on a page that will return a zip file. I can get the file but I can't for the life of me figure out how to write the in memory zip file to an actual file on the filesystem. I've been searching all day but it seems to be a well kept secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ZipFile` instance should have `.fp` attribute which in your case would be referring to the `StringIO.StringIO` holding your content (in general it should be the file-like object underlying content of `ZipFile`), hence:

```
zip.fp.seek(0)  # To make sure the read for write start from the beginning
with open('outfile.zip', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(zip.fp.read())
```

Should do the trick. ;)